# How remove vertical gap between words using css

Tags: html, css

I have this span within button

```
<span style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: 700; white-space: normal; margin-left: -5px;">UPGRADE PLAN</span>
```

Here `white-space: normal` breaking word UPGRADE PLAN vertically. But I can not remove vertical gap between them.[Here you can see gap between upgrade and plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rZc4d.png). But I want it like this means [no gap between these two words](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuWBd.png). 
How can I achieve this.

Comment: adjust line-height

Comment: your code doesn't correspond to the image at all. But with line-height you can adjust it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set the line height lesser than the font size as below:

```css
span{
 max-width: 80px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 9px;
}
```

```html
<span style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: 700; white-space: normal; margin-left: -5px;">UPGRADE PLAN</span>
```